# How to remove the last replaced string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this string example below and a working code.

**Code Output**

*D8-E7-44-T7-TU-J7-*

**Desired Output**

*D8-E7-44-T7-TU-J7*

```js
var numberss = 'D8E744T7TUJ7';
alert(numberss.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1-"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to split the string 2 characters at a time, and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it back again.

```js
var numbers = 'D8E744T7TUJ7';
alert(numbers.match(/.{2}/g).join('-'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [positive look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match two characters only if it followed by two characters.

```js
var numberss = 'D8E744T7TUJ7';
alert(numberss.replace(/.{2}(?=.{2})/g,"$&-"));
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit of your code?. can't read this line `/.{2}(?=.{2})/`

Comment: @KiRa :  `(?=.{2})` checks the pattern follows 2 character... which helps to avoid last 2 characters

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice to delete last character

```js
var numberss = 'D8E744T7TUJ7';
alert(numberss.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1-").slice(0,-1));
```

Hope it helps for you!!!